# Spring get session class object

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, session

I am trying to get the class object from session attribute. Here is the code

IndexController.java

```
User user = new User();
user.setEmail("EMAIL");
user.setName("name");
session.setAttribute("session_user", user);
```

index.jsp

```
<c:choose>
     <c:when test="${session_user != null}"
Hello <c:out value="${session_user[user.getName()]}">
     </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

But it is not printing anything?

Comment: why not use `ModelAndView` object? Also you cannot use methods in JSTL

Comment: @FarazDurrani, already done!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace that Hello line in your index.jsp with:

```
Hello <c:out value="${session_user.name}">
```

Those EL expressions don't understand getter/setters you just type the property name to get the value out of it. And what is [...] for? You are not going over `List`.